# Get Sql Table Relationships using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, relationship

I'm trying to get all the relationships of a table using ADO.Net.  I have the following code below, but am unable to get Data.Relations or DataSet.Tables[0].ChildRelations/ParentRelations

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM {0}", tableName);

var ds = new DataSet(tableName);
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

sda.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, tableName);
sda.Fill(ds, tableName);

sda.Dispose();
```

Thanks!

Comment: u can use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo namespace

Comment: I've came across that solution but do not want to implement that, because I soon want to support OLEDB connection, and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it much thought, I'm going to do Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.  As it will save me a lot of time. As for other data providers, when the time comes, I'll write similar code. If I end up writing a good API, I will definitely make it open source and share it with others.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the results from a [`DbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) doesn't return any information about the relationship of the tables that were used to form the projection of the values that are returned (they're not really needed beyond the query).

That said, you can call the [`GetSchema` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s98te64s.aspx) to help get the information about the relationships.

When called without parameters, it will give you a list of all the metadata collection types available through that collection.  In the case of a [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) one of those collections is "ForeignKeys".

You can then make a call like this:

```
DataTable foreignKeys = connection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys");
```

Which will then give you a listing of all the foreign keys that exist in that database.

That said, each call to `GetSchema` is specific for the *provider*; there's no guarantee that `GetSchema` will return the same data collections or the same format across different providers.  The result you get for Oracle, ODBC, OLE-DB, MySql, etc, can potentially all be different, and you have to account for those differences yourself.

Comment: I can account for all the different providers, as long as I stick to one API (ADO.Net).  Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Hey, I gave it a try. The schema only gives me information on the table that has the foreign key, not the table that the foreign key references.

Comment: @Pathachiever11 Short of querying the underlying data stores for that data, there isn't a way built into .NET to do this.